# How do I remove everything after second ":" in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I am not sure if this is possible but I would like to change

candy:apple:good to candy:apple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regular expression in the search replace box, then find and replace.

```
/candy:apple(:\w+)/
```

Note: Make sure Regular expression radio button is the one checked.